# Pending transactions in DBeaver connected to a PostgreSQL DB (autocommit is set to OFF and I launch a COMMIT command from sqleditor worksheet)

Tags: postgresql, transactions, dbeaver

I'm trying to learn transactions management in PostgreSQL (I'm an Oracle PL/SQL programmer); using DBeaver I face myself with the following problem:

I run this script

```
DO
$$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM my_table;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMIT;
```

it runs smoothly but when I look at pending transactions I find that there are two pending transactions that need to be committed (I get rid of them only using the "COMMIT" button on the IDE).

[image: In red the button I need to use to get rid of the green pending transactions]

I expect to have no pending transaction after the commit in the script, where do I get it wrong?

Comment: Those two green rows of a status of `Success` so I guess they are already finished. But the summary says it displays 2 of 5 - so the "open transactions" might be the other three that are not shown. What do you see when you select `show all connections` and `show all queries`

Comment: If I check the two boxes no other transaction appear on the list. I have rollbacked all the transactions, closed and reopened DBeaver and relaunched the script, same as before but this time it says 2/4. I think the two pending are the ones with **Success** because in the first attempt DBeaver says "2 pending transactions" and not 3 (refer to the image in the question)